# How do I specialize generic higher order function in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am unit some http code in swift. In my test class I have the function :

```
func measureAsync<T>(_ block: @escaping ((Result<T>) -> Void) -> ()) {
    self.measure {
        let expect = self.expectation(description: "get from backend")
        block { (result) in
            expect.fulfill()
            XCTAssertNotNil(result.value, "value")
        }

        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error", error)
            }
        }
    }
}

public func curry<A, B, C>(_ f : @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> C {
    return { (a : A) -> (B) -> C in
        { (b : B) -> C in
            f(a, b)
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to call the function in my test case like this:

```
    let block = curry(StorageClient.client.getProfilePicture)(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/User Photos/profile_MThumb.jpg"))
    measureAsync(block)
```

And I get the compiler error "Cannot convert value of type `'((Result<UIImage>) -> Void) -> ()'` to expected argument type `'((Result<_>) -> Void) -> ()'`

How do I get this to compile? Is it even possible?

Comment: seems incomplete... we might need to see `curry()` method

Comment: Of course. Edited*

Comment: How do you mean? Should I make an extension for all types that I want to download?

Comment: my bad :P, use this `let block : (((Result<UIImage>) -> Void) -> ()) = curry(StorageClient.client.getProfilePicture)(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/User Photos/profile_MThumb.jpg"))`

Answer (score 0):

I "Solved" it. It's kind of a hack. But it does the job

```
func testProfilePicture() {
    let block = curry(StorageClient.client.getProfilePicture)(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/User Photos/profile_MThumb.jpg"))
    measureAsync(UIImage.self, block)
}

func measureAsync<T>(_ type: T.Type, _ block: Any) {
    self.measure {
        let expect = self.expectation(description: "get from backend")
        if let block = block as? (((Result<T>) -> Void) -> Void) {
            block { (result: Result<T>) in
                expect.fulfill()
                XCTAssertNotNil(result.value, "value is nil")
            }
        } else {
            fatalError("could not downcast block")
        }

        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```